# how can i get value of node in treeview when checkbox is checked in asp.net by jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, treeview

i have a simple asp:treeview

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" 
    ShowCheckBoxes="Leaf"
    OnTreeNodeCheckChanged="CheckChanged"      
    ShowLines="true"
    PopulateNodesFromClient="true"
    ShowExpandCollapse="true"    
    NodeIndent="10"> 
</asp:TreeView>
```

and i do this

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
        function client_OnTreeNodeChecked(event) {
            var treeNode = event.srcElement || event.target;            
            if (treeNode.tagName == "INPUT" && treeNode.type == "checkbox") {
                if (treeNode.checked) {
                    alert(treeNode.value);                                      
                }
            }
        } 
</script>
```

but i only get "on" in alert.
how can i get value of node instead of value of checkbox?